# Get user friends list with firebase in one query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure for storing users and their friends, note that there is a node called `friends` in each user node and the key of the objects inside the `friends` node is the friend user id.

```
  "users" : {
    "{user_1}" : {
      "email" : "geek@live.com",
      "firstName" : "Geek",
      "friends" : {
        "{user_2}" : {
          "status" : "pending",
          "with" : {
             "firstName" : "Anna", 
            "profileImage" : "http://..."
          }
        }
      }
    } ,
    "{user_2}" : {
      "email" : "anna@live.com",
      "firstName" : "Anna",
      "friends" : {
        "{user_1}" : {
          "status" : "pending",
          "with" : {
             "firstName" : "Geek",
             "profileImage" : "https://..."
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

my goal is to get the user friends in one query, here is what I have tried:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
             .queryOrderedByChild("friends")
             .queryEqualToValue(currentUserID)
             .observeEventType(.Value) { firDataSnapshot in
              print(firDataSnapshot)
}
```

so I have tried to get all users that has the current userID as a key in their friends node, but without luck.

*Note that I can query only the node inside the user, but then I will not get the full users node of friends*

Comment: Are you trying to get all friends for a specific user? In that case just listen for the node "friends" under that user's uid

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I was curious if there was a way to get it from each friends node of all user, is that possible ?